# Integration shows different result after manual u-substitution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

I'm working with sine and cosine integral functions, and stumbled on this weird issue when performing integration in Mathematica.

I worked out the following integral by hand and found:

\begin{equation}
    \int_{-A}^{A} \frac{\sin(B(t-t_0)+Ct)}{t-t_0} dt = \\ \sin(Ct_0)     \Big(\textrm{Ci}\big((B+C)(A-t_0)\big)-\textrm{Ci}\big(-(B+C)(A+t_0)\big)\Big) + \\cos(Ct_0) \Big( \textrm{Si}\big( (B+C)(A-t_0)\big) + \textrm{Si}\big((B+C)(A+t_0)\big) \Big),
\end{equation}

with $\{A, B, C\} \in \Re_0$, and $\textrm{Si}, \textrm{Ci}$ denoting the Sine Integral and Cosine Integral function, respectively.

However, when I try to solve the same integral in Mathematica, I get a different solution:

```
Integrate[Sin[B (t - t0) + C t] / (t - t0), {t, -A, A}, GenerateConditions -> False] //FullSimplify
>(CosIntegral[-((B + C) (A - t0))] - CosIntegral[(B + C) (A + t0)]) Sin[C t0] + Cos[C t0] (SinIntegral[(B + C) (A - t0)] + SinIntegral[(B + C) (A + t0)])
```

where the argument of the first two Cosine Integral functions is suddenly negative compared to my solution by hand. I am fairly certain of my solution, so it would suprise me if I solved it incorrectly somehow.

Something I did try, was performing u-substitution by hand first, which results in:

$$\textrm{Let } u = B(t - t_0) + C t, \\\\$$

$$\int_{-A(B+C)-Bt_0}^{A(B+C)-Bt_0} \frac{\sin(u)}{u-t_0C} du$$

and solving **this** integral using Mathematica. This does give me my original solution again:

```
Integrate[Sin[u]/(u - t0*C), {u, -A (B + C) - B t0, A (B + C) - B t0}, GenerateConditions -> False] // FullSimplify
>(CosIntegral[(B + C) (A - t0)] - CosIntegral[-((B + C) (A + t0))]) Sin[C t0] + Cos[C t0] (SinIntegral[(B + C) (A - t0)] + SinIntegral[(B + C) (A + t0)])
```

So I don't really understand why Mathematica gives a different result before and after the u-substitution (assuming that my u-substitution is correct).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Mathematica's definition of the cosine integral function,](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/CosIntegral/16/01/01/) we have
$$
\text{Ci}(-x) = \text{Ci}(x) + \ln(-x) - \ln(x) = \text{Ci}(x) + i \pi
$$
for $x > 0$.  This then implies that $\text{Ci}(-x) - \text{Ci}(-y) = \text{Ci}(x) - \text{Ci}(y)$.  In other words, the two forms of the integral are functionally equivalent so long as $x > 0$ and $y > 0$.

Mathematica can be induced to show this using `FunctionExpand` — though if I try to prove the above statement using `Reduce`, it returns `False`, which is strange.  It's entirely possible that I'm missing something.

```
Reduce[
 {CosIntegral[x] - CosIntegral[y] == FunctionExpand[CosIntegral[-x] - CosIntegral[-y])], 
  x > 0, y > 0}, Reals]

(* False *)
```

Comment: I think you get `False` because there are no real values for which `Log[-x]` and `Log[x]` are real-valued.  The domain spec. `Reals` in `Reduce` means "all constants and function values are also restricted to be real."

Comment: @MichaelE2: Hmm, that makes sense. Without the `Reals` option, it returns `Log[-x] == Log[x] + Log[-y] - Log[y]` instead, which is (I think) true so long as `x` and `y` are both negative or both positive.  I was hoping to get Mathematica to print `(x > 0 && y > 0) || (x < 0 && y < 0)` as its final answer, but I couldn't cajole it into doing so.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot for the helpful answer. I'm gonna look into it!